# Using calculations in range for formulas

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sum up a range of cells using an array formula, but trying to dynamically change the end of the range based on the value in cell B7. My current array formula is:

```
=SUM(IF({1},'Summary Data'!S362:S393))
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the end of the range (S393) to add the value in B7. B7 is currently 31, so right now 362 + 31 = 393.

I've tried using INDIRECT and storing a string of the cell I want somewhere else. Something like putting this in cell A18:

A18 ="S" & 362 + $B$7

```
SUM(IF({1},'Summary Data'!S362:INDIRECT("a18"))
```

Which is probably a bad way (and also doesn't work). Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: Why are you using SUM as an array formula and not just `=SUM('Summary Data'!S362:S393)`?

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason I needed to use an array formula. I had used one earlier (where it was actually useful) and guess my brain got stuck in that mode =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUM does not need to be an array formula, but to add the rows use INDEX not INDIRECT as INDIRECT is Volatile:

```
=SUM('Summary Data'!S362:INDEX('Summary Data'!S:S,362 + B7))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the return value of INDEX could be used as a reference.